# How to open clipboard on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows, clipboard

Where is the exact location of clipboard folder in Windows 7? In XP I could find the `clipbrd.exe` but whereas clipbrd.exe was a command line tool in windows 7

Is there any way to open the clipboard in Windows 7 and other updated versions?

P.S : Installing third party tools was restricted at my machine so any other built-in way to deal with this?

Comment: [Free Clipboard Viewer v3.0](http://www.freeclipboardviewer.com/)

Comment: I know this is an older question, but what exactly do you mean by the "clipboard folder" and the "open the clipboard"? Do you just need to view the clipboard content?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

AFAICT `clipbrd.exe` has been removed beyond XP, and there isn't a replacement Windows tool to view the clipboard.

However, if you still have an XP installation kicking around somewhere copying over the executable has apparently been "known to work"<sup>[1](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/windows-clipboard-manager-viewer)</sup>:

> You can try to copy it from a Windows XP installation, if you have access to it, and paste it in your System32 folder. In most cases this is known to work.

**Edit**: Per testing, this works in Windows 7 (and Windows 8.1, incidentally).

Otherwise, there are several third-party clipboard viewers; including one offered (and several alternatives noted) by the above link.

Comment: *"However, if you still have an XP installation kicking around somewhere copying over the executable has apparently been 'known to work'...*" Not in Windows 10 it doesn't.

Comment: [there's a replacement in Windows 10](https://superuser.com/a/1440576/241386)

Answer (score 5):

#### "Where is the exact location of clipboard folder in windows 7?

In Windows 7 or later there is no longer a built in clipboard program.

You can use one of the many 3rd party alternatives if you want to manage the clipboard.

The link below lists some 3rd party products.

---

#### Clipboard in Windows

> In Windows XP this file was situated in
> `C:\Windows\System32\clipbrd.exe`.
>
> It is now missing as a part of the Windows 10 / 8 / 7 installation.
> You can try to copy it from a Windows XP installation, if you have
> access to it, and paste it in your System32 folder. In most cases this
> is known to work.

Source [View & Manage Clipboard In Windows 10 / 8 / 7](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/windows-clipboard-manager-viewer)

Answer (score 4):

Windows 7 comes with PowerShell 2.0 preinstalled and you can use it to **manipulate the clipboard directly** with [`Windows.Forms.Clipboard`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.clipboard?view=netframework-4.8) (or [`Windows.Clipboard`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.clipboard?view=netframework-4.8) in PresentationCore). Some examples

```powershell
Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationCore
[Windows.Clipboard]::GetText()
$out = "some text"
[Windows.Forms.Clipboard]::SetText($out)
[Windows.Clipboard]::GetData([Windows.DataFormats]::UnicodeText)
[Windows.Clipboard]::GetData([Windows.DataFormats]::Html)
if ([Windows.Clipboard]::ContainsFileDropList()) {
    $f = [Windows.Clipboard]::GetFileDropList()
    Write-Host $f
}

if ($out)
{
    [Windows.Clipboard]::SetText($out);
}
else
{
    [Windows.Clipboard]::Clear();
}
```

The first line can be changed to `Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms` along with some replacements:

- `[Windows.Clipboard]` → `[Windows.Forms.Clipboard]`
- `[Windows.DataFormats]` → `[Windows.Forms.DataFormats]`

---

You can even write a [PowerShell script](https://theitbros.com/powershell-gui-for-scripts/) [with **GUI**](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/stephap/2012/04/23/building-forms-with-powershell-part-1-the-form/) to view and edit the clipboard. Fortunately there's an already-made solution here: [Building a Clipboard History Viewer Using PowerShell](https://learn-powershell.net/2014/07/24/building-a-clipboard-history-viewer-using-powershell/)

> I saw a question a while back in the Technet PowerShell Forum asking how one might start to build a clipboard viewer using PowerShell that met a few requirements:
>
> - Have an open window aside from the PowerShell console
> - Automatically list new clipboard items as they come in
> - Allow for filtering to find specific items
>
> [image: Clipboard history viewer GUI]

You can also download the script directly from [MS Technet Gallery](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/PowerShell-Clipboard-c414ec78). Note that it only supports text so you'll have to modify it if you want to include other data formats like images or files

---

Another solution for PowerShell 2.0 is the module [ClipboardText](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ClipboardText/0.1.7) which can be installed with `Install-Module -Name ClipboardText`

```powershell
Set-ClipboardText "some text"
Get-ClipboardText
```

It's also available on [GitHub](https://github.com/mklement0/ClipboardText)

---

If you have access to PowerShell 5.0 and up, you can use the built-in cmdlets [`Get-Clipboard`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-clipboard?view=powershell-5.0) and [`Set-Clipboard`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-clipboard?view=powershell-5.0) directly. They support not only text but also other objects in clipboard. Some examples

```powershell
Get-Clipboard -Format Text -TextFormatType Html
Get-Clipboard -Format FileDropList
(Get-Clipboard -Format FileDropList)[0].GetType()
```

See also [New Stuff - Get-Clipboard And Set-Clipboard - New In PowerShell 5.0](https://thomasrayner.ca/new-stuff-get-clipboard-and-set-clipboard-new-in-powershell-5-0/)

There also various portable applications for clipboard manipulation