# What do I need to do to view my clipboard in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, clipboard

In order to view what is in my clipboard, do I need to download a special program? And if so, where can I find that program? I am using Windows 10 OS on an HP computer.

Answer (score 3):

You just need to press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>. Since October 2018 Update a synced clipboard has been introduced along with a history viewer

[image: Clipboard settings]

[image: Clipboard history]

- [Clipboard in Windows 10](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/clipboard-in-windows-10-c436501e-985d-1c8d-97ea-fe46ddf338c6)
- [How to use the new clipboard on Windows 10 October 2018 Update](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-use-new-clipboard-windows-10-october-2018-update)
- [How to Use the New and Improved Windows 10 Clipboard](https://sea.pcmag.com/microsoft-surface-book-2-15-inch/29910/how-to-use-the-new-and-improved-windows-10-clipboard)

---

You can also manage the clipboard directly with PowerShell. Windows 10 has built-in PowerShell 5.0 so you can run [`Get-Clipboard`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-clipboard?view=powershell-5.0) and [`Set-Clipboard`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-clipboard?view=powershell-5.0) from it

```powershell
Get-Clipboard -Format Text -TextFormatType Html
Get-Clipboard -Format FileDropList
(Get-Clipboard -Format FileDropList)[0].GetType()
```

Alternatively you can use [this script](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/PowerShell-Clipboard-c414ec78) which is a GUI written in PowerShell to show the clipboard

[image: Clipboard history viewer GUI]

More information can be found in my answer to [How to open clipboard on Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/a/1440152/241386). See also

- [New Stuff - Get-Clipboard And Set-Clipboard - New In PowerShell 5.0](https://thomasrayner.ca/new-stuff-get-clipboard-and-set-clipboard-new-in-powershell-5-0/)
- [Building a Clipboard History Viewer Using PowerShell](https://learn-powershell.net/2014/07/24/building-a-clipboard-history-viewer-using-powershell/)

Answer (score 1):

You just need to copy the Clipboard Viewer (clipbrd.exe) from a Windows XP machine to your C:\PROGRAM FILES (x86). It is also available to download [from here](http://www.freeclipboardviewer.com/clipbrd.exe.html).

Alternatively you could opt for one of the more powerful alternatives including:

- [ClipboardMASTER](https://www.clipboardmaster.com/)
- [ClipMagic](http://www.clipmagic.com/)
- [Ditto](https://sourceforge.net/projects/ditto-cp/)