# How do convert unsigned hex to decimal in Windows 10 Calculator?

Tags: windows-10, conversion, calculator, hexadecimal

I'm using the Windows 10 Calculator in Programmer mode to convert hex to decimal. The issue is the calculator defaults to signed.

> Set to: DWORD
>
> HEX: A08A 5A52

Result:

> DEC: ‭-1601545646‬

How do I set it to give an unsigned value?
I find I can get unsigned if I just use a larger memory value, setting it to QWORD, but then I run into problems if using a unsigned 32-bit value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I set it to give an unsigned value?

Binary files are represented as signed 2’s compliment within the Windows Calculator.  As such, Windows Calculator, doesn’t support unsigned binary values.

I suggest using a different calculator program for your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Use PowerShell instead. Just type `0xA08A5A52L` and the result in decimal will be printed out. If you have [PowerShell 6.2 or newer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57477641/995714) you can also use `0xA08A5A52UL`. The `L` and `UL` suffixes denote `long` and `ulong` types in .NET respectively

[image: PowerShell demo]

Windows Calculator doesn't have the ability to deal with unsigned values as of now, so you have to use a wider type which is QWORD for DWORD values. You'll only run into problems when dealing with unsigned 64-bit values. For 0xA08A5A52 if you're operating in DWORD mode then you'll need to change to QWORD mode then do a bitwise `AND` with 0xFFFFFFFF to clear the high order bits to get the unsigned value 2693421650 correctly

---

Off-topic, but in fact if you want a calculator for programmers then PowerShell would be more appropriate because it's far more versatile and powerful than Calculator. I'll show some more examples on how PowerShell can be used for that purpose. For doing math in .NET (and inherently PowerShell) there exists math functions from low to high levels, mainly from the [.NET Math class](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math?view=netcore-3.1) and [Numerics namespace](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics?view=netcore-3.1). You'll put class .NET types inside `[]`, like `[math]` or `[system.math]` for the `Math` class (PowerShell is case-insensitive). Apart from that there are some other things that may be useful to programmers:

- Bitwise operations (bitwise operators begin with `-b` except shift operators)

  ```
  [uint64]::MaxValue/3 + (-bnot 20) + (1L -shl 22) + (0x23 -band 0x34)
  ```
- [Big integer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.biginteger?view=netcore-3.1) math: `[bigint]::Pow([uint64]::MaxValue, 20)`
- Arbitrary integer and floating-point math expressions

  ```
  1.56 + 0.23/[math]::Pow([math]::Sqrt([math]::Log(20) + [math]::Sin([math]::PI/3)), 4)
  ```
- Math on [decimal type](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/floating-point-numeric-types) (128-bit): `1.23d * 3.45d / 28`
- Math on [128-bit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uint128) [integer types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int128)
- [Matrix](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.matrix4x4), [quaternion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.quaternion), [plane](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.plane), [vector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.vector), [complex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.complex)... math
- Calculate file or object sizes: Use number suffixes `12.5GB + 5.8MB + 1392KB` for binary units and `12.5e9 + 5.8e6 + 1392e3` for decimal units (G = 1e9, M = 1e6, K = 1e3)
- Convert to/from base64: [`[Convert]::ToBase64String`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.tobase64string?view=netframework-4.8) and [`[Convert]::FromBase64String`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.frombase64string?view=netframework-4.8)
- [Date/time](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime?view=netcore-3.1) manipulation. For example convert from raw Epoch values to datetime and vice versa

  ```
    [datetime]::FromFileTime(0x01d15614cbaee92c)
    [datetime]::ParseExact("08-12-2012","dd-MM-yyyy", `
            [Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture)
  ```
- String formatting and base conversion. Anything that [`String.Format`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.format?view=netcore-3.1) in .NET supports will work. For more information read about the [formatting operator](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7#format-operator--f). You can also do advanced string and regex manipulation. Some examples:

  ```
    'somestring'.Substring(4) * 3 -replace 'ings', 'eet'
    '{0:X}' -f (0x12 + 34)
    [convert]::ToString(0x12 + 34, 16)
    'This is an emoji' + [char]::ConvertFromUtf32(0x1F60A)
  ```
- Direct [XML](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-xml?view=powershell-7), [CSV](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-csv), [JSON](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json?view=netcore-3.1)... manipulation
- Call functions in *.SO/*.DLL files directly
- GUI programming. Here's a small sample [clipboard history app](https://superuser.com/a/1440152/241386)

  [image: PowerShell sample]

For more information read

- [Doing Math with System.Math](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/samples/using-static-classes-and-methods?view=powershell-7#doing-math-with-systemmath)
- [Using PowerShell to Work with Numbers](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/using-windows-powershell-to-work-with-numbers/)
- [Playing with JSON and PowerShell](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/playing-with-json-and-powershell/)
- [Time conversions in PowerShell (and .NET in general)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/sergey_babkins_blog/time-conversions-in-powershell-and-net-in-general)
- [Understanding Numbers in PowerShell](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/understanding-numbers-in-powershell/)

or follow [Dr Scripto's blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/author/the-scripting-guys/)